# Diffrences between "as" and "the more"

Tags: sentence-structure

> **As** emerging economies continue to expand, their energy needs are set to grow dramatically

What is diffrences between this two sentence, have it the same meaning or not?

> **The more** emerging economies continue to expand, **the more** their energy needs are set to grow dramatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, minor correction:

> As emerging economies continue to *expand,* their energy needs are set to grow dramatically.

I assume you meant expand here, as you wrote in your second sentence.  *Expend* word here would make the clause turn into "As emerging economies continue to expend their energy", but the rest doesn't make a complete sentence.

So what's the difference between:

> As emerging economies continue to expand, their energy needs are set
>   to grow dramatically

And..

> The more emerging economies continue to expand, the more their energy
>   needs are set to grow dramatically

While both establish a relationship, I would argue that the first sets a very general trend.  The growth of economy implies growth of energy needs.

The second would seem to imply a mathematical trend (linear, exponential, or otherwise).  Of course, don't get me wrong, neither one is giving figures or data to support this claim, but in let's say that the latter case would suggest that such a relationship *can* be established between the two.

If you wanted to go further, you might say something like:

> The energy needs of an economy is directly proportional to its growth.

Comment: I would also add that "as *(something happens)*" tends to imply that that is actually occurring now, or is expected to occur.  "the more *(something happens)*" is often used in the same way, but can also just mean "if this thing happens more, then that thing will happen more", without necessarily saying that that is going to happen in any specific case.